# Does the "version" in Composer git repository refer to the release (tag) on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, composer-php

I need to use Composer to manage a dependency (normalize.css and others) without `composer.js` in the project root. I ended up defining a package but I have a few questions:

```
{
    "require": {
        "twbs/bootstrap": "~3.0",
        "fortawesome/font-awesome": "~3.2",
        "necolas/normalize.css": "*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type":"package",
            "package": {
                "name": "necolas/normalize.css",
                "version":"2",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference":"master"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Does the `version` in my package refer to a release (tag) in the GitHub repository? If yes, how can I specify i.e. `~2.1` (I get invalid package definition) or the latest tag available?

For `necolas/normalize.css` I'd like to always get the latest version of the master branch.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution:

For test purpose I have this composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "mycompagny/composer-project",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "http://localhost/git/test.composer.dep.git"
        }
    ],
    "require" : {
        "mycompagny/test.composer.dep": "dev-master#v2.0.0"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

In the require key, put #youversion after dev-master to point to your git tag "yourversion".

The tag after # here act as a commit.
(according to : https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links)

Comment: It seems to be the case that you can type whatever you want after the # and composer will pull always the latest commit.

Answer (score 5):

> "Does the version in my package refer to a release"

No, a version inside a `package` entry defines the version number that Composer should refer to this package as.

Setting the `version` explicitly is required for packages unfortunately, even if they are coming from Git.

> "how can I specify i.e. ~2.1 (I get invalid package definition) or the latest tag available?"

It looks like you can't. The version listed in a package has to be an actual version number, rather than a version number range, and there's no way to fetch the tags from Git, which sucks.

If you were to replace using a Package repository to using a zipball Artifact package, it would be really easy to add a composer.json with the relevant info after you've downloaded the zipball from Github.

I've added that as a proof of concept to https://github.com/Danack/IntahwebzRepo , which is a simple script to download zipballs from Github, and then either add a version entry to their composer.json, or completely generate a composer.json if they don't already have one.

Once the zipballs are downloaded and modified it then uses them in a Satis (aka Packagist) repository.

Comment: That is, wiping the version from the package will let me specify the version the usual way (require + semver)?

Comment: Doesn't work. When you remove version from package you gent an error when running composer (invalid package definition).